# Open a Thickbox with content trough AJAX

Tags: ajax, editor, thickbox

I added a custom button to the TinyMCE editor, and I want to open WP's Thickbox when I click on it.

How can I make it so that the `tb_show()` function loads the content I want with ajax?

```
// the ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_getTheContent', 'getTheContent');
function getTheContent(){
  echo 'weqwtegeqgr'; // <- this should be displayed in the TB
  die();
}
```

Here's some of the editor plugin code I'm using:

```
init : function(ed, url) {
  ed.addButton('do_stuff', {
    title : 'Do Stuff',
    image : url + '/icon.gif',
    onclick : function() {
        OpenMyThickbox('do_stuff');
    }
  });
...
```

So the `OpenMyThickbox` javascript function should do what I want:

```
function OpenMyThickbox(tag){
  tb_show(tag, '...'); // <- how to load content trough ajax here ?
}
```

Comment: use admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); for url

Comment: I get a blank page. even if I enter google.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter for `tb_show` is the URL, so you'll want to use something like..

```
<?php 
$ajax_url = add_query_arg( 
    array( 
        'action' => 'getTheContent', 
        'query_var1' => 'value1', 
        'query_var2' => 'value2' 
    ), 
    admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) 
); 
?>
tb_show(tag, '<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>' );
```

I'd guess you need to pass the action and any additional query vars manually(as per above), else your request is simply for `admin-ajax.php`, when what you are looking for is something along the lines of ... `admin-ajax.php?action=getTheContent&someothervar=someothervalue`, hence the `add_query_arg` usage above..

**For clarification:**

The following call to `add_query_arg` ...

```
add_query_arg( 
    array( 
        'action' => 'getTheContent', 
        'query_var1' => 'value1', 
        'query_var2' => 'value2' 
    ), 
    admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) 
);
```

Is equivalent to and will produce ...

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getTheContent&query_var1=value1&query_var2=value2
```

#### However!

Having now explained myself i've come to realise we don't want the absolute URL and thus don't need the call to `admin_url` in there. The code should instead be.

```
<?php 
$ajax_url = add_query_arg( 
    array( 
        'action' => 'getTheContent', 
        'query_var1' => 'value1', 
        'query_var2' => 'value2' 
    ), 
    'admin-ajax.php'
); 
?>
tb_show(tag, '<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>');
```

So the resulting URL looks something like this..

```
admin-ajax.php?action=getTheContent&query_var1=valu1&query_var2=value2
```

Functions referenced in the above code samples:

- **Add Query Arg**
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg
- **Admin URL**
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url

Comment: Won't that be a `$_get['action']` because WordPress ajax call looks for `$_post['action']`? or am i wrong?

Comment: It'll be `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` inside an ajax callback typically, unless you explicitly set your ajax request function to use `get` instead, in the context of a thickbox call, we use a query string, which should still show up in `$_REQUEST` (because that usually holds both `$_GET` and `$_POST`)..

Comment: No, what i'm asking is if i  use `add_query_arg` will the args added be sent as a post or get?

Comment: Neither, `add_query_arg` appends a string(of a url) with query parameters, it doesn't do any sending, so i'm not sure i understand your question..

Comment: Updated my answer..

Comment: Nevermind. just looked at the admin-ajax.php and in the first lines it checks for `$_REQUEST['action']` so i got my answer, thanks. +1

Comment: Ah yes, i realise what you mean now... sorry for not picking up on what you meant... :)

Answer (score 3):

Messing up javascript and PHP is not very clever. This answer only confuse.

tb_show is javascript
add_query_arg is PHP

so this solution is only valid in PHP and the proper code is

```
...
?>
tb_show(
  'whatever',
  <?php echo add_query_arg( array(
    'action' => 'getTheContent',
    'query_var1' => 'value1',
    'query_var2' => 'value2',
  ), 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>
);
<?php
...
```

And in javascript is not valid at all as we can't use add_query_arg

Comment: Where is that different from the solution aside from it having the `<?php ?>` tags in it? If that's all that you want to point out, then please make an edit to the solution to correct it. No need to add a separate answer to explain what's wrong with another answer. That's why community edits are appreciated.

Comment: @kaiser Edits changing the meaning of a post are usually not welcome. As a separate answer this is okay.

Comment: @toscho And how exactly is this changing the _meaning_ ? Imo it's _correcting_ or _adding the missing bits_.

Comment: Bayen was correct to point out the mistake here, i was mixing PHP and Javascript, i really should of spotted that sooner. I've made the necessary changes to my answer, and thanks for the feedback bayen(i like to know when i make errors).